# API help commission junction

Tags: api, commission-junction

Im new to the realm of API and I was wondering do I need to paste the code as is or would I need to add javascript and interface to it myself? Im working with commission juntion datafeeds and developer key to make a website that is similar to www.directtextbooks.com

Below is the website link with the instructions that they provide 
http://help.cj.com/en/web_services/Product_Catalog_Search_Service_v.2.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to get data from cj, but the results of the data is for what ever you want to use it for.

Before you start working with API's you should look into programming applications.